# Multithreading events handling request

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, c#-4.0

I'm currently working on a program  which connects a web application with a third party client application which runs on the webserver. The Application is working as a connection between the web and the third party app. Every single request is going onto my "connector" application.

The application is a Windows forms application (because the third party application is one too... don't ask me why...) written in C# and needs to be open all the time. Breaking everything down the application looks like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}

    private void UserEvent(UserEvent e, long threadID)
    {
        load();
    }
```

The UserEvent() is getting triggered by the web. When triggered, data will be loaded out of the third party app and then 'returned'. These requests can take up to 3 seconds. Right now, there were no problems because I was the only person using this connection. To make it multithreadable, I now need to do the load(); in another thread in case the UserEvent gets triggered while application is still loading data for the frevious user.

Now to my question: What would you suggest me to use? Threads or Backgroundworkers?
Even if I do the whe whole loading in another thread, isn't there still the possibility that UserEvent() is getting triggered by two Users at the very exact same time causing the application to crash?

Any suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Its no problem if `UserEvent(...)` is getting triggered multiple times as long the method does not share or access ressources that aren't safe for concurrent access themselves. Packing things into threads or tasks (did you already have a look at the [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?) does not solve your problems concerning thread-safety.

In the worst case your third party component can not run multiple instances simulanously (e.g. if it accesses some common background ressources). But than your solution can look like:

```
private readonly object x = new object();
private void UserEvent(UserEvent e, long threadID)
{
    lock(x) 
    {
       load();
       // ...
    }
}
```

So this is probably not what you are searching for. I would suggest you first isolate the parts that *can* and those, that *can't* run simlutanously. Then apply suitable locking mechanisms to eliminate concurrency problems. And in the end e.g. pack thing into a task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    //..
});
```

Of course you can fine-tune a lot. But therefore details are needed.

---

**Edit:**  I assume your `UserEvent` might already get called by different threads. That's the reason for the locks in the first example. If this is not the case and speed is your concern, you sure want to execute things asynchronously.